# Transform string to XML by replacing placeholders with XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

Dear StackOverflow members,

I am working in C#. I have the following string:

```
"This {1} is {2}really{3} great {4}, isn't it?"
```

Where the placeholders between curly brackets might correspond to the following tags (contained in an array):

Case 1:

```
{1} = <cf underline="single">
{2} = <cf bold="True">
{3} = </cf>
{4} = </cf>
```

or 
Case 2:

```
{1} = <cf underline="single">
{2} = </cf>
{3} = <cf bold="True">
{4} = </cf>
```

i.e. nodes at the same level or nodes with childnodes.

I would like to insert the tags in my segments, which can be done easily by looping in my array and replace the corresponding placeholders with the specified value. That is the easy part.
However, I would like to insert an attribute in the opening element which would contain the ID of the opening and the closing tag so that my XML would look like this:

Case 1:

```
<seg>
 This
  <cf underline="single" startID=1 endId=4>
   is 
    <cf bold="True" startID=2 endId=3>
     really
    </cf>
     great 
  </cf>
 , isn't it?"
</seg>
```

Case 2:

```
<seg>
 This
  <cf underline="single" startID=1 endId=2>
   is 
  </cf>
  really
  <cf bold="True" startID=3 endId=4>
   great 
  </cf>
 , isn't it?"
</seg>
```

Does anyone have a hint for me on how to achieve this? I have been looking for a solution on this for many hours but I don't even see where I could start.

I thank you all in advance for your support.

Regards,

Laurent

Comment: How comfortable are you working with stack data structures?

Comment: Hi @hoodaticus , I have already worked with stacks but I am not sure how I could use them in this specific case. One more hint ;-) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally don't try and manipulate Xml using strings. It's a headache and you'll screw it up many times before you get it right. Use XmlDocument.

For your template replacement you can use strings. Then I'd suggest converting it to an xml document and walking down it to set your attributes afterwards.

Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{


    public static void WalkXml(XmlElement node, ref int index) {

        node.SetAttribute("startIndex", index.ToString());

        foreach(XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes) {
            XmlElement element = (child as XmlElement);
            if (element != null) {
                index++;
                WalkXml(element, ref index);
            }

        }
        node.SetAttribute("endIndex", (++index).ToString());
    }

    public static void WriteXml(string message, string[] tags) {
        var xmlStr = $"<seg>{String.Format(message, tags)}</seg>";
        var xmlObj = new XmlDocument();
        xmlObj.LoadXml(xmlStr);

        int index = 1;
        WalkXml(xmlObj.DocumentElement, ref index);     

        Console.WriteLine(xmlObj.InnerXml);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] tags1 = new string[] {
            "<cf underline=\"single\">",
            "<cf bold=\"True\">",
            "</cf>",
            "</cf>"
        };

        string[] tags2 = new string[] {
            "<cf underline=\"single\">",
            "</cf>",
            "<cf bold=\"True\">",
            "</cf>"
        };      

        string message = "This {0} is {1}really{2} great {3}, isn't it?";

        WriteXml(message, tags1);
        WriteXml(message, tags2);
    }

}
```

Here's the output

```
<seg startIndex="1" endIndex="6">This <cf underline="single" startIndex="2" endIndex="5"> is <cf bold="True" startIndex="3" endIndex="4">really</cf> great </cf>, isn't it?</seg>
<seg startIndex="1" endIndex="6">This <cf underline="single" startIndex="2" endIndex="3"> is </cf>really<cf bold="True" startIndex="4" endIndex="5"> great </cf>, isn't it?</seg>
```

the demo code puts indexes on "seg" as well but it shows the idea and you should be able to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Hi @JamesT, Thank you for your help. Your answer enabled me to assign the correct Ids I both cases. A big thank you. I feel stupid because I already implemented the whole logic, the only thing I was missing was an index which I increment after I processed an element. I believe I worked too long on this and could not see the obvious.

Comment: No worries. Fresh pair of eyes and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.  You are really doing things a little backwards.  You are adding the xml between the strings, instead of adding the strings into the xml.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication43
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] input = { "This", "is","really", "great",", isn't it?"};
            KeyValuePair<int, int>[] startEndId = {
                new KeyValuePair<int,int>(1,4),
                new KeyValuePair<int,int>(2,3)
            };


            var seq = new XElement("seg", new object[] {
                input[0],
                new XElement("cf", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("underline", "single"),
                    new XAttribute("startID", startEndId[0].Key),
                    new XAttribute("endID", startEndId[0].Value),
                    input[1],
                    new XElement("cf", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("bold", "True"),
                        new XAttribute("startID", startEndId[1].Key),
                        new XAttribute("endID", startEndId[1].Value),
                        input[2],
                    }),
                    input[3],
                }),
                input[4]
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dear @jdweng, thanks for your solution. However, I opted for the solution of JamesT since I was following the same logic but for other purposes. Thanks for offering your help.